# Plotting a graph using user input for theta and omega

Tags: javascript, html, forms, canvas, input

What I'm trying to do is create a page on which you can input the frequency(omega) and phase(theta) for a sine or cosine function and it will be graphed for you once you click submit. I found a tutorial online for the actual graphing of the equation at http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-graphing-an-equation/  but it doesn't allow for user input. Don't know how to grab those values and insert them into the graphing equation. It only works for when I manually assign a value to the input boxes in the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>

    <form onsubmit="plot()">
    Omega:<input type="text" id="omega" value=2><br>
    Theta:<input type="text" id="theta" ><br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="300"></canvas>

    <script>
     // Lots of code here for actually graphing the function. See the link for the entire code 

      // variables to grab the values
      var omega=document.getElementById("omega").value;
      var theta=document.getElementById("theta").value;


        //function plot(){
          myGraph.drawEquation(function(x) {
            return Math.sin(omega * x + theta);
          }, 'green', 3);
        //}

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correctly fetching the user's omega & theta `.values`.

Now create a button that fetches the values and replots the sine function:

```js
document.getElementById('plot').onclick=function(){
      var x=1;
      var omega=document.getElementById("omega").value;
      var theta=document.getElementById("theta").value;
      // Demo: Just show the values and the computed sine value
      // In your code: send the values into your sine-plot code
      alert('sine('+omega+'*1+'+theta+')=='+Math.sin(omega * x + theta));
};
```

```html
Omega:<input type="text" id="omega" value=2><br>
Theta:<input type="text" id="theta" value=10 ><br>
<button id=plot>Plot</button><br>
```